# jquery Dialog reappears on postback

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a GridView with a TemplateField holding a LinkButton. When this button is clicked it converts some XML that is in another hidden TemplateField to a string and assigns it to a label in a hidden div to be used in a modal dialog. Currently the dialog opens as expected with the proper information, it closes and I can select another record in the grid to view with no problems. This is where it goes wrong and I have not been able to find a solution. If I do something else on the page that causes a postback, the last dialog box to be opened will open on the new page load.

Here is my relevant mark-up:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtBeginDate").datepicker();
    $("#txtEndDate").datepicker();

    $("#response").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        title: "Equifax Response",
        close: function(ev, ui) {
            $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
        }
    });

    $("[id*=lnkEquifaxResponse]").on("click", function EquifaxResopnse() {
        $("#lblDialog").empty();
    });

    if ($("#lblDialog").text() != "") {
        $("#response").dialog("open");
    }
});
    </script>

    <div id="response" visible="false">
        <asp:Label ID="lblDialog" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </div>

    <div id="Gridview">
        <asp:GridView ID="grClientTransactions" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
            PageSize="25" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ResponseXML"
            EmptyDataText="Record not found." EmptyDataRowStyle-BackColor="#CCCCCC" EmptyDataRowStyle-Font-Bold="true"
            CssClass="mGrid" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" 
            AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" 
            OnPageIndexChanging="grClientTransactions_PageIndexChanging" 
            onrowcommand="grClientTransactions_RowCommand">

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEquifaxResponse" runat="server" CommandName="EquifaxResponse" Text="View" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "RowIndex") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField Visible="false" HeaderText="Equifax Response">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblEquifaxResponse" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ResponseXML")%>' ></asp:Label></div>                            
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

            </Columns>
            <PagerStyle CssClass="pgr" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alt" />
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

I am new to programming so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like this:

```
 <div id="response" visible="false">
    <asp:Label ID="lblDialog" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label>
 </div>
```

As far as I understand, when you click on a link, lblDialog is filled with some data on server and because of viewstate is enabled that data is restored on each postback. Than, `if` shown below returns true and popup is appears.

```
if ($("#lblDialog").text() != "") {
    $("#response").dialog("open");
}
```

If you will  add enableviewstate="false", inner text of lblDialog will be lost on second postback and lable will be empty after page is loaded (if not a link in grid is clicked).

You can get more info about viewstate and how it works [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! that did it. I have been beating my head on this for 2 days now.